# I want to create, expand and collapse the UITableview list, when they click the UI Button (found in my cell)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, swift2

I want to create list as in uploaded picture and I have tried with AccordingCells in swift code but not much help have any one steps to create this types of list view in swift 2.2.

[image: example list]

I have tried to edit them inside the cell code but am still receiving an error. Please let me know what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a expanding animation called `VPAccordionAnimation` which is used for such kind of expanding and collapsing feel.

Using that class, you can create a custom view with 3 buttons and pass that view as a parameter and everything will be handled by that class.

Let me know if you need any help.